# `kubectl logs` on Azure AKS yields error "Forbidden (user=system:anonymous ..)"

Tags: azure, kubernetes

Whenever I try to run `kubectl logs` on azure, I get the following error:

> Error from server (Forbidden): Forbidden (user=system:anonymous, verb=get, resource=nodes, subresource=proxy) ( pods/log )

A similar error is returned for `kubectl exec`, `kubectl attach` and most helm commands:

> error: unable to upgrade connection: Forbidden (user=system:anonymous, verb=create, resource=nodes, subresource=proxy)

This is a default azure aks installation. Problems started after upgrading from 1.8.10 to 1.9.x

```
kubectl api-versions
```

admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1alpha1
admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1
apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
apiregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1
apps/v1
apps/v1beta1
apps/v1beta2
authentication.k8s.io/v1
authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
authorization.k8s.io/v1
authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
autoscaling/v1
autoscaling/v2beta1
batch/v1
batch/v1beta1
certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1
events.k8s.io/v1beta1
extensions/v1beta1
networking.k8s.io/v1
policy/v1beta1
rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
storage.k8s.io/v1
storage.k8s.io/v1beta1
v1

```
kubectl version
```

Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9", GitVersion:"v1.9.1", GitCommit:"3a1c9449a956b6026f075fa3134ff92f7d55f812", GitTreeState:"clean",BuildDate:"2018-01-04T11:52:23Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9", GitVersion:"v1.9.6", GitCommit:"9f8ebd171479bec0ada837d7ee641dec2f8c6dd1", GitTreeState:"clean",BuildDate:"2018-03-21T15:13:31Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Comment: As a temporary workaround for development i logged into the node and changed the /etc/defaults/kubelet file to use --authorization-mode=AllowAll instead of WebHook. I can `kubectl logs` now, but exec, attach and helm still don't work and i don't think this is a viable solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i managed to create a workaround by applying this yaml:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: anonymous-logs-role
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["nodes/proxy"]
  verbs: ["create", "get"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: anonymous-logs-binding
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: anonymous-logs-role
subjects:
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: User
  name: system:anonymous
```

this way logs, exec and attach work and the api server doesn't expose any information. not sure if there are any drawbacks...

Answer (score 0):

This command will give your user (you) a cluster-admin role.

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding me-cluster-admin \
    --clusterrole=cluster-admin \
    --user=system:anonymous
```

Comment: That's right, but this gives cluster admin access to everyone - even on the web API. The yaml i posted doesn't give anonymous access to the web API. Still not sure if my solution is safe to use in production though.